# Is the IN operator in Crystal Reports case sensitive?

Tags: crystal-reports, case-sensitive

I have a long list of strings that I need to compare a column against and I am wondering if doing this `{table.column} IN ['ABC']` is the same as this `{table.column} IN ['abc']`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a setting in File -> Report Options that tells CR if your SQL statements need to be case sensitive.  That setting also controls the case sensitivity of your Crystal formula comparisons.  This setting is saved with each report so you can have some reports that are case sensitive and others that are not. You can set the global default for this setting in File -> Options (Database Tab).  The File Options setting will set the default value for all NEW reports, but will not change the default value for existing reports.  If you need to change the value for existing reports you need to go to File -> Report Options for each report.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough answer. I appreciate it!